# How to deploy javaFx desktop application in server

Tags: java, javafx

I hava an application Java built with JavaFx and I want to run it from server,
my problem is I want to connect it to a remote database and I don't want to autorize all the access also I don't have time to create an API to control requests.
do you have any suggestions?

Comment: The GUI is always the front end, not the back end. I don't see how the server gets involved in running the app... The database should allow you to create multiple users with multiple roles. Just give everyone exactly the access that they need and nothing more. Triggers/constraints can help keeping database integrity, but in certain cases you won't get around writing a server...

Comment: Thank you, but I have spring installed and there are four layers dao,service ... and desktop layer so can I deploy the services and dao layer in server

Comment: Can you explain more your problem ,do you want to run your application as web application or you need to create remote server/remote database connection ?